# Identity Server 3. How can I redirect to a specific uri after call method SignIn?

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

My code in ASP.NET MVC:

```
var context = Request.GetOwinContext();
context.Authentication.SignOut();
context.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SiteUri"] + "Callback" }, (ClaimsIdentity)CurrentUser.Identity);
```

My code in IdentityServer  `Client.cs`:

```
RedirectUris = new List<string>
{
     ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUri"],
     ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUri"]+"Callback"
}
```

I'm expecting a call `CallbackController` , but this is not happening. What could be the reason??

Comment: Specify the redirect url in the MVC site. This should match one of the urls you've specified in the client.cs.

Comment: At the moment, i use next way. After call SignOut/SignIn i save `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` in Session (may be Cashe). I specified one url in Client.cs  - CallbackController. In action CallbackController/Index i read saved url from Session and call `Redirect(savedUrl)`.

Answer (score -1):

RedirectUri is an endpoint that will be called after successful authentication of user on identity server login page in implicit flow.

Since there is no information about method where code for SignIn is placed, i can just guessing that something like this will help:

```
await SignInMethod(HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication, ....);
return new RedirectResult(string.Format("{0}{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUri"], "callback"));
            }
```

Comment: I call SignIn in method `void OnActionExecuting` in Controller. I cant use `return new RedirectResult(...)`